# assign variables to argparse not through command line

Tags: python, pytest, argparse

I am trying to write tests (using pytest) for a script, but I don't know how to create/pass arguments to main(), especially when it doesn't recieve arguments. and even if I change it to `def main(args = None):` then it'll initiate it on the first line.

**tests.py**

```
def test_main(capfd):
    main()
    out, err = capfd.readouterr()
    assert out == "my expected output"
```

**script.py**

````
def init_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="The script searches one or \
                                     more named input files for lines \
                                     containing a match to a regular \
                                     expression pattern.")
    parser.add_argument('regex', help='the regular expression.')
    parser.add_argument('infile', nargs='*', type=argparse.FileType('r'), default=[sys.stdin],
                        help='the name of the file(s) to search.')
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    group.add_argument('-u', '--underscore', action='store_true', help='prints \
                       "^" under the matching text.')
    group.add_argument('-c', '--color', action='store_true', help='highlights \
                       matching text.')
    group.add_argument('-m', '--machine', action='store_true', help='generates \
                       machine readable output.')

    return parser


def main():
    args = init_parser().parse_args()
    for file in args.infile:
        for i, line in enumerate(iter(file.readline, '')):
            for substring in re.finditer(args.regex, line):
                    if args.underscore:
                        underscore_output(file.name, i + 1, line[:-1],
                                          substring.start(), substring.end())
                    elif args.color:
                        color_output(file.name, i + 1, line[:-1],
                                     substring.group())
                    elif args.machine:
                        machine_output(file.name, i + 1, substring.start(),
                                       substring.group())
                    else:
                        print_line(file.name, i + 1, line[:-1])```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the test code, you would [patch](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html) out `sys.argv` before calling `main`:

```
def test_main(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr("sys.argv", ["script.py", "test_regex", "test_infile"])
    main()
    # put your assertions here
```

Answer (score 2):

`parse_args` can take an explicit `None` argument to tell it to parse `sys.argv[1:]`. Write your code so that it can be easily tested:

```
def main(args=None):
    args = init_parser().parse_args(args)
    ...
```

In production use, you'll call `main()` to let it parse `sys.argv`. For tests, you'll pass a *specific* set of arguments.

```
def test_main(capfd):
    main(['[a-z]*', 'foo.txt', '-u'])  # For example
    out, err = capfd.readouterr()
    assert out == "my expected output"
```